# How does this prove that Doctor Strange is a Doctor Strange from another universe?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

In *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* we saw

> the Darkhold Strange (the one with 3rd eye) asking Doctor Strange to prove that he is another Doctor Strange from another universe, to which Doctor Strange replied telling the story of their sister who died.

But as we know, different versions of people in different universes might have different events in their lives, and what Doctor Strange said might not be what happened in other universes, so how is that a proof that

> the Darkhold Strange accepted?

Comment: I don't think wanted proof that 616 Strange was from another universe; I think he wanted proof that 616 Strange was actually a Doctor Strange, rather than some sort of extra-dimensional or supernatural imposter. As you say, different Doctor Stranges have lived somewhat different lives, but apparently Darkhold Strange had gone through the same tragedy with his sister as 616 Strange, and that was enough to convince him that he was talking with another Doctor Strange.

Comment: _”Darkhold Strange: Sounds about right... but we don’t talk about that do we?”_ this makes it seem like the story isn’t exactly the same in that universe. However, he knew that they had a sister who died. It just turned out to be a fortunate coincidence that they both had something similar happen with Donna.

Comment: Spoiler : Sorry I might have forgotten the ask, but the question still stands, why does Doctor Strange even consider telling the story knowing that the Darkhold Strange might not share the same events? I mean there is a risk that the Darkhold Strange didn't even have a sister, then Doctor Strange would just be a liar

Comment: Alternate question: how else would he prove it? And sharing a story that only they would know that’s quite meaningful to them is a quick and easy enough place to start.

Comment: You are still using 'they' as if it is guaranteed that they both have the same events, that is incorrect

Comment: 'How else would he prove it?' is not something that answers this question, it is something that points to a hole in the plot.

Comment: Something not being explicitly explained is not a “hole in the plot”. In fact in this case it doesn’t really need to be because apparently they have had relatively similar lives.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136681/discussion-between-mocas-and-thelethalcarrot).

Answer (score 9):

**Skip to the bolded part of the last paragraph for the tl;dr version of this answer.**

There's a trope in fiction where characters whose identities are in doubt (i.e. they might be an imposter, or possessed by someone else) are asked to prove they are who they *say* they are by saying [something only they would say](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SomethingOnlyTheyWouldSay), or know.

For example, in  *X-Men* (2000), there's a scene where Cyclops suspects Wolverine might be Mystique in disguise, so he asks him to prove he's really Wolverine, and Wolverine does so by telling Cyclops that he's a dick. This wasn't much in the way of proof, but it was sufficient for Cyclops in that context, since Mystique likely wouldn't have known of his and Wolverine's dislike for one another.

In this case, 'Darkhold Strange' asked 'our' Strange to prove he was who he *claimed* to be (i.e. another Strange from another universe), and Strange reasoned that one way of doing so would be to share a childhood memory that only another Strange who experienced a similar childhood would be likely to know.

> DARKHOLD STRANGE: Who are you... what are you?
>
> STRANGE: I'm just, one of us.
>
> DARKHOLD STRANGE: From the Multiverse?
>
> STRANGE: That's right.
>
> DARKHOLD STRANGE: Prove it.
>
> STRANGE: We had a sister. Donna. She, uh... She died, when we were kids.
>
> DARKHOLD STRANGE: How?
>
> STRANGE: We were... playing on a frozen lake, and... She fell through the ice. I couldn't save her.
>
> DARKHOLD STRANGE: Sounds about right. But we don't talk about that, do we?
>
> STRANGE: No, we don't.

There's no guarantee that the sharing of this memory would've been sufficient, as Darkhold Strange might've had a very different childhood for all our Strange knew. But Darkhold Strange's reply suggests he did experience that event also, and that this revelation did therefore persuade him that our Strange was telling the truth.

The sharing of this memory also doesn't directly prove that our Strange was from another universe, but as indicated by Darkhold Strange's dialogue, he already had that possibility in mind, and in having been persuaded that he was speaking to another Strange, it made sense to also conclude that this other Strange was from another universe.

There are other possible conclusions -- like this other 'Strange' could've been an imposter with the ability to read minds -- but **I think the point of this exchange was not for him to prove *beyond all reasonable doubt* that he was another Strange from another universe, but merely that *on the balance of probabilities*, this was the most likely explanation.**

Comment: @Mocas - Let me know if there are any relevant points you feel I haven't covered in this answer, and if I can, I'll attempt to address them with an edit.

Answer (score 0):

> different versions of people in different universes might have different events in their lives

That's true, but it's implied that there are certain events that are the same in every universe. For example, at the end of the film, 616 Strange tells Christine,

> I love you in every universe.

Taking Strange at his word, this means that every universe's version of him is guaranteed to meet that universe's Christine and fall in love with her, regardless of whatever else may happen in that universe. It could well be that the death of his younger sister, and his subsequent refusal to talk about it, is another guaranteed event, and if it is, Darkhold Strange has met enough Stranges to figure out that it's something they all go through.

Answer (score -1):

I came here while looking for answers to this peculiar interaction.
Leaving a trace here, for others to ponder.

The specific way this interaction went made me think..
that maybe Darkhold Strange simply wanted proof that 616 Strange was a real "Doctor Strange".
One of the ways to prove this, is by telling him the traumatic way he got started on his path.
The way all variants of Dr Strange get their powers.

Otherwise I feel like they would have let Darkhold Strange say something different, like about the details.
They could have gone so many other ways with that reply.

Not something we talk about indeed.

Comment: Your answer appears to echo the reasoning already provided in the [existing answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/263743/122024) to this question. It's only really worth posting a new answer to an old question if you have some genuinely new reasoning or evidence to offer.

Comment: Ah right. New here so couldn't comment yet.

To me there is actually a significant enough difference in my words.
In similar posts I see people write about the accuracy of an event the Doctors may have shared. 

I believe that the event itself was not as important as the type of event. Darkhold Strange needed to see the scar that made 616 Strange. The chance of their events somehow being identical should be multi-astronomical.

Comment: _"The chance of their events somehow being identical should be multi-astronomical."_ Perhaps on paper, but in practice, we're shown that variants of the same person in the Marvel multiverse often have very similar backgrounds. Take the three Peter Parkers in _No Way Home_, who were all orphans raised by their versions of Uncle Ben and Aunt May. The fact that you have two Dr. Stranges from two realities, who look identical and are both sorcerers living in the same Sanctum Sanctorum, in itself suggests that they likely had similar backgrounds.